# 'ssh localhost' gives 'Permission denied (publickey).'

Tags: 12.04, ssh, localhost

I'll mention some of many things I tried and give a couple of diagnostics.  I would appreciate any clues on how to debug this:

```
me@myubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh localhost
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Previously I ran

```
sudo ufw allow ssh/tcp
```

and set up port forwarding for port 22 in my router, and verified that is open [here](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) (but maybe not necessary -- does ssh even go out as far as the router when I ssh to myself?).

In my home/.ssh directory I did `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys` and set up the permissions with `chmod 600 authorized_keys`.

Running `ssh -v localhost` gives lots of output, and here is the last few lines where I think the problem happens:

```
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: me@myubuntu
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I succeeded in ssh-ing to my bitbucket repository, so I think this implies that my id_rsa key set is valid and has the correct permissions.

**Update 1:**

```
> ~/.ssh$ ls -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 me me 747 Oct 25 08:27 /home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(looks good)

**Update 2:**

```
~/.ssh$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drwx------ 2 me me 4096 Oct 25 08:27 /home/me/.ssh
```

(looks good)

**Update 3:** Last few lines of `/var/log/auth.log` right after I run `ssh localhost`:

```
Oct 25 09:49:47 me-myubuntu sshd[16442]: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 36944
Oct 25 09:49:47 me-myubuntu sshd[16442]: User me from localhost not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Oct 25 09:49:47 me-myubuntu sshd[16442]: input_userauth_request: invalid user me [preauth]
Oct 25 09:49:47 me-myubuntu sshd[16442]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

Well look at that!  I previously messed with the sshd_config file and forgot to correctly specify my AllowUsers option.

SOLUTION: Include `localhost` in the `AllowUsers` line in `sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: check the stats of `authorized_keys` file. What does `ls -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` return?

Comment: Yes. I see. And the `.ssh` directory? `ls -ld ~/.ssh`. What is in error log, on debian I guess `/var/log/auth.log` related to the login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check `/var/log/auth.log` for possible errors during connection. This line

> Oct 25 09:49:47 me-myubuntu sshd[16442]: User me from localhost not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers

indicates the problem.